# Can't create a drop down button for my sorting method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Dropdown doesn't work. It shows up as dropped down all the time.

I have tried using something like the dropdown from react-boostrap; however that didn't work for me either. In that case the button never drops down. I tried downgrading my version of react-bootstrap but if I do that my code will break.

```
import React from "react";
import './Brewery.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ButtonToolbar, DropdownButton, MenuItem } from 'react- 
bootstrap';


class Brewery extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMenu: false,
      breweries: [],
      isOpen: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  toggleOpen = () => this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });

  sortAlpha() {
      const breweries = [...this.state.breweries.slice(0,10)].sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
        if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
        return 0;
      });
      this.setState({ breweries: breweries });
    }

  sortRevAlpha() {
    const breweries = [...this.state.breweries.slice(0,10)].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name < b.name) return 1;
      if (a.name > b.name) return -1;
      return 0;
    });
    this.setState({ breweries: breweries });
  }

 render() {

   const { breweries } = this.state;

   return(
    <div className="main-container">
      <div className="banner" styles="background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,101,168,0.6) 0%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 50%), url('http://bitterminnesotabrewerytours.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/boston-beer-tours-glass.jpg');">
        <div className="banner-content">
          <h1>Brewery</h1>
          <p>Find the best brewery in town</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="container">
      <div className="dropdown">
        <button
        className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        id="dropdownMenuButton"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={this.toggleOpen}
        >
        Dropdown
        </button>
        <div aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a className="dropdown-item" href="#nogo">
            Item 1
          </a>
          <a className="dropdown-item" href="#nogo">
            Item 2
          </a>
          <a className="dropdown-item" href="#nogo">
            Item 3
          </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.sortAlpha()}>Sort Alphabetically</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.sortRevAlpha()}>Sort Rev Alphabetically</button>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {breweries.slice(0, 10).map((brewery, i) =>
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" key={i}>
              <Link to={`/brewery/${ brewery.id }`}>
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-description">
                    <h2>{brewery.brewery_type}</h2>
                    <p>{brewery.city}, {brewery.state}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-category"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/20/000000/beer.png"/>  {brewery.name}</div>
                </div>
              </Link>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Brewery;
```

Comment: Try changing to onClick={() => this.toggleOpen}

Comment: Doesn't change anything, still shows up dropped down all the time

Comment: It should be fairly straightforward to do this vie react-bootstrap... but if you want a custom this should help yu out... https://blog.logrocket.com/building-a-custom-dropdown-menu-component-for-react-e94f02ced4a1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't gone through with setting up the `Router` and testing everything locally, but when I did paste this into my IDE it shows that in the code you never actually use:

`import { ButtonToolbar, DropdownButton, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';`

Edit:

Removed a few things and brought in react-bootstrap. Works just fine.

```
import React from "react";
import { ButtonToolbar, DropdownButton, MenuItem } from "react-bootstrap";

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMenu: false,
      breweries: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data
        });
      });
  }

  sortAlpha() {
    const breweries = [...this.state.breweries.slice(0, 10)].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
      if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
    this.setState({ breweries: breweries });
  }

  sortRevAlpha() {
    const breweries = [...this.state.breweries.slice(0, 10)].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name < b.name) return 1;
      if (a.name > b.name) return -1;
      return 0;
    });
    this.setState({ breweries: breweries });
  }

  render() {
    const { breweries } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="main-container">
        <div
          className="banner"
          styles="background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,101,168,0.6) 0%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 50%), url('http://bitterminnesotabrewerytours.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/boston-beer-tours-glass.jpg');"
        >
          <div className="banner-content">
            <h1>Brewery</h1>
            <p>Find the best brewery in town</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <ButtonToolbar>
            <DropdownButton
              bsSize="small"
              title="Small button"
              id="dropdown-size-small"
            >
              <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey="3">Something else here</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem divider />
              <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
            </DropdownButton>
          </ButtonToolbar>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.sortAlpha()}>Sort Alphabetically</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.sortRevAlpha()}>
            Sort Rev Alphabetically
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {breweries.slice(0, 10).map((brewery, i) => (
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" key={i}>
              <div className="card">
                <div className="card-description">
                  <h2>{brewery.brewery_type}</h2>
                  <p>
                    {brewery.city}, {brewery.state}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div className="card-category">
                  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/20/000000/beer.png" />{" "}
                  {brewery.name}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Make sure you add a link to bootstrap CSS at the bottom of your index.html in `/public` or react-bootstap won't work. It's just a wrapper.

```
// shortened to show code needed
  <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </body>
```

Here is it working:

[image]

Comment: I have this because I've been trying different things to get a dropdown button including those from react-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks! This worked, I forgot to add the link to bootstrap and that's why it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't actually using `this.state.isOpen`. Your `toggleOpen` method toggles it, but I think you'll need to connect that `this.state.isOpen` value to your menu.

Ultimately you'll have to decide where you want it, but one solution that I've used before is to put it before your breweries `map`, so that the breweries list will only render if `isOpen` is truthy:

```js
{ this.state.isOpen && breweries.slice(0, 10).map( // the rest of your code block here.
```

Also, since you're already destructuring `this.state` at the top of your `render()` method, I'd probably keep that consistent and pull out `isOpen`, and then remove the `this.state` from the `&&` check.

Let me know how that goes or if you've got any questions.